# Creating 2d array out of a text file in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I've got a following example file

```
Name#Last#Age#Height
Test#Test2#20#180
Peter#Brown#45#190
```

I want to make a 2d array out of if so it looks like this

```
{
    {"Name", "Last", "Age", "Height"},
    {"Test", "Test2", "20", "180"},
    {"Peter", "Brown", "45", "190"}
};
```

Can anyone help me find the correct solution?

Comment: You can use File.ReadAllLines to split the rows, and the method Split of the String object on each Row to split the array of words.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");

var arr = new int[lines.Length, 4];

// TODO: loop through the lines and fill the array
```